# keep a Python script running even when the user tries to exit out

Tags: python-2.7

Is it possible to keep a Python script running even when the user tries to exit out of it by clicking the x (exit) button? thus meaning that the only way to exit will be, suppose like have the quit() command within the script.

The question sounds dumb, but I am CURIOUS!!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: x button of what kind of window?

Comment: I'm tempted to answer "no" but, before I do, could you say what operating system you're thinking about and if you're running a Python program in a console or as a GUI? There may be system-specific ways of blocking a user from exiting a program that way.

Comment: first of all my intentions are not of hacking or something of that sorts, further the "X" means the exit out button of the script/console screen that pops up when you click on it and yes the program is running in a console screen, with win XP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I did find the answer with Tkinter. I had my script run a while loop with a Tkinter dialog that asks for userInput. The script is saved with the `.pyw` so the user cannot exit out of the script and exiting out of the Tkinter dialog just makes it reappear again. I will not be posting the code here, because I do not want my code to lead to bad things.